# Windows "Last Accessed" Attribute

Tags: windows, iis

I have a Windows IIS server with images that are accessed by web sites.

When an end user hits my web page, and an image is displayed, the image comes from the Windows server.

When an image is displayed, will the "Last Accessed" attribute on the windows server be updated ?

Comment: Why down vote ?

Comment: That's one of the reasons for a server to write a log file so you can see which resources where requested.

Comment: `Why down vote ?` - Probably because it took you longer to post this than it would have taken to test yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If that file system capability is enabled, yes.  Many people disable the NTFS LastAccessed functionality for performance reasons, so I would not assume that it is updated.  If you are looking for a capability to report on some statistics, I would first check that registry value:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
"NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate"=dword:00000001

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file is actually accessed (and not a cached copy), then yes, the last accessed attribute will be updated.